# Sequelize: Error creating a post and associating it with the current user

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I get an error creating a post and trying to associate it with the current user:

```sh
SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value
```

this is my method

```js
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const {title, content, userEmail} = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: userEmail
        }
    })
    if (user) {
        const post = await Post.create({
            title, content, image: req.file.originalname, userId: user.id
        })
        res.json(post)
    }
}
```

Tried with `user: user` as well.

This is my user model

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Post)
  };
  return User;
};
```

This is the post model, where the belongsTo relation is declared

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.STRING,
    image: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  };
  return Post;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not define association in right way . you can do like this .

**User Model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {});
    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Post, {
            foreignKey: 'userId',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        })
    };
    return User;
};
```

**Post Model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        userId: DataTypes.INT,
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        content: DataTypes.STRING,
        image: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {});
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: 'userId',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        })
    };
    return Post;
};
```

**Query be Like :**

```
const { title, content, userEmail } = req.body;
const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
        email: userEmail
    },
    raw: true
})
if (user) {
    const post = await Post.create({
        title, content, image: req.file.originalname, userId: user.id
    })
    res.json(post)
}
```

Comment: thanks @Vyas Arpit, yes, that's the same solution i found and i was about to post. I thought the foreignKey in camecase format was considered the default thus no need to declare it.

Comment: happy to have helped :)